# Cyclic dependency in smart contracts?

Tags: solidity

How can we manage cyclic dependency in solidity smart contracts?

for example:

```
contact A {
   B b = B();

}

contract B {
 A a = A()
}
```

Comment: The snippet you provided will never deploy either due to surpassing the gas stipend or the EVM stack limit, whichever comes first. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What you are describing above is not a cyclic (circular?) dependency. You are just having an infinite loop where a contract deploys a contract which deploys a contract which deploys a contract until you run out of gas. In any other language this will not work as well, you will run out of memory at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option #1 - if you want to support initialization only from the off-chain:

**File `IA.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface IA {
    // Declare here every function which you want to invoke
    // from other contracts (i.e., not from the off-chain).
}
```

**File `A.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./IA.sol";
import "./IB.sol";

contract A is IA {
    IB public b;
    function set(IB _b) external {b = _b;}
    // Implement the rest of the contract here.
}
```

**File `IB.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface IB {
    // Declare here every function which you want to invoke
    // from other contracts (i.e., not from the off-chain).
}
```

**File `B.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./IA.sol";
import "./IB.sol";

contract B is IB {
    IA public a;
    function set(IA _a) external {a = _a;}
    // Implement the rest of the contract here.
}
```

Option #2 - if you want to support initialization from both the off-chain and the on-chain:

**File `IA.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface IA {
    // Declare here every function which you want to invoke
    // from other contracts (i.e., not from the off-chain).
    function set(address _b) external;
}
```

**File `A.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./IA.sol";
import "./IB.sol";

contract A is IA {
    IB public b;
    function set(address _b) external {b = IB(_b);}
    // Implement the rest of the contract here.
}
```

**File `IB.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

interface IB {
    // Declare here every function which you want to invoke
    // from other contracts (i.e., not from the off-chain).
    function set(address _a) external;
}
```

**File `B.sol`:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "./IA.sol";
import "./IB.sol";

contract B is IB {
    IA public a;
    function set(address _a) external {a = IA(_a);}
    // Implement the rest of the contract here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get around the circular reference error, I've answered that question here: 
[Can a contract copy itself? [Circular reference for contract creation (cannot create instance of derived or same contract)]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/can-a-contract-copy-itself-circular-reference-for-contract-creation-cannot-cr/48612#48612)

> I wrote an article on how to get around this on medium.
>   https://medium.com/@kylebryant_28277/subverting-the-circular-reference-error-in-solidity-f7167bf9fdb
>   Basically you need to create two new contracts, one that makes a new contract of the type you want, and an abstract contract of that one. I call these the Maker and Supplier contracts. Give it a read :)!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract VotethComment {

    string public comment;
    string public nickname;
    address public author;
    address[] public votethComments;
    address votethCommentMaker;

    constructor(string _comment, string _nickname, address _author, address _votethCommentMaker) public {
        comment = _comment;
        nickname = _nickname;
        author = _author;
        votethCommentMaker = _votethCommentMaker;
    }

    function addComment(string _comment, string _nickname) public {
        VotethCommentSupplier votethCommentSupplier = VotethCommentSupplier(votethCommentMaker);
        votethComments.push(votethCommentSupplier.makeComment(_comment, _nickname, msg.sender));
    }
}

contract VotethCommentSupplier {
   function makeComment(string _comment, string _nickname, address _author) public returns(address);
}

contract VotethCommentMaker {
    function makeComment(string _comment, string _nickname, address _author) public returns(address) {
        return new VotethComment(_comment, _nickname, _author, this);
    }
}
```